# How to count a boolean value from a map

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Used Framework is Angular 8

I have an array called `teams` of which i can get the length by using `teams.length` .
Now `teams` has a map called `teamInfo` for each count. This teamInfo map has again a boolean value `isClosed` that can be accessed by `teams.teamInfo.isClosed` for each count, when jsoning it into the ngforloop, which is

```
*ngFor=" let teamID of JSObject.keys(teams); trackBy: trackByFn

<app-team-card
[team]="teams[teamID]"
[isClosed]="teams[teamID].teamInfo.isClosed">
</app-team-card>
```

My goal is to get the number of all maps that have `isClosed =true.` My attempt was

```
getClosedTeams(teams) {
         let closedTeams = teams.teamInfo.filter((isClosed) => {
             return isClosed.select == true;
        });
        console.log(closedTeams.length);
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Also change the comparison ```isClosed.select == true``` to ```isClosed.select === true```

Comment: Also you said teamsInfo is map , map does not has a filter property . You use filter with an array . Better if you can provide the data in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do something like this:

```js
const team01 = new Map();
team01.set('name', 'team-01');
team01.set('isClosed', false);

const team02 = new Map();
team02.set('name', 'team-02');
team02.set('isClosed', true);

const team03 = new Map();
team03.set('name', 'team-01');
team03.set('isClosed', true);

const teams = [team01, team02, team03];

function getClosedTeamsCount (teams) {
  return teams.reduce((acc, teamInfo) => {
    return Number(teamInfo.get('isClosed')) + acc;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(getClosedTeamsCount(teams));
```

Comment: teams is an array , then it has teamInfo as map , which has isClosed property. Will this work ?

Comment: As far as teams is an array, it should work. You just need to access isClosed property for each element of the array.

Comment: I understand that , but is the property isClosed part of teams array or teamInfo map inside teams array? Check the question once  ```I have an array called teams of which i can get the length by using teams.length . Now teams has a map called teamInfo for each count. This teamInfo map has again a boolean value isClosed ```